# Problem with yaml

Tags: ros, rospy, yaml, pip

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I use ROS Indigo on Raspbian. When I try turn on a program, I have got error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/hil/scripts/hil.py", line 2, in <module>
    import rospy
  File "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    exec(__fh.read())
  File "<string>", line 49, in <module>
  File "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_comm/rospy/src/rospy/client.py", line 47, in <module>
    import yaml
ImportError: No module named 'yaml'
```

My program code is:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python3
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String
#added
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist 


def callback(data):
    global msg
    if data.data=="Unknown":
        pub = rospy.Publisher('cmd_vel', Twist) 
        rospy.loginfo("Classifiers output: %s in unknown" % data.data)
        msg.linear.x = 2
        msg.linear.y = 2
        msg.angular.z = 0
        speed = 0.4 
        rospy.loginfo("checking for cmd" + str(msg.linear))
        pub.publish(msg)
    elif data.data=="Check":
        rospy.loginfo("Classifiers output: %s in check" % data.data)
    else:      
        rospy.loginfo("Classifiers output: %s and not unknown or check" % data.data)

   

def listener():

     global msg
     rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)
     msg = Twist()
     rospy.Subscriber("ccc", String, callback)
     rospy.spin()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    

    listener()
```

I tried

```
sudo apt-get install python-yaml
```

yaml is installed, but error still appears

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278954/problem-with-yaml/) by [aefka](https://answers.ros.org/users/33160/aefka/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2018-01-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't tell us which version of Raspbian you are using, but this is most likely a Python 2 vs Python 3 problem.

For typical platforms `apt-get install python-yaml` will install the Python 2 library.

From the shebang in your Python script:

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/python3
> ```

you appear to run your script(s) using Python 3. As `yaml` is most likely not installed for that, the runtime can't find the module.

I suggest you switch to Python 2, as that is the default -- and best supported -- in all currently released ROS releases.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-05**:
Note also btw that this is not really a ROS issue, but a regular Python / package installation one.

**Comment by [aefka](https://answers.ros.org/users/33160/aefka/) on 2018-01-05**:
Very thanks, but my code still don't work, despite the error has disappeared.
I wnat to publish msg. linear.x and msg.linear.y to V-REP to topic cmd_vel. I have no idea what i doing wrong :/

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-05**:
That would seem to be a different issue. I recommend you post a new question. This is not a forum, but a QA site, and those work best with a 1-to-1 ratio of questions and answers.